# Citrus framework ftp connection

Tags: xml, spring, ftp, citrus-framework

I'm trying to know better [citrus framework](http://citrusframework.org) for integration tests. 
I try to create ftp sender but I have following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file]
```

Offending resource: class path resource [citrus-context.xml]

Here's my part of citrus-context.xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:citrus="http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/config"
   xmlns:si="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
   xmlns:file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
   xmlns:citrus-ws="http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/ws/config"
   xmlns:citrus-http="http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/http/config"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/config 
   http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/config/citrus-config.xsd
   http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/ws/config 
   http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/ws/config/citrus-ws-config.xsd
   http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/http/config 
   http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/http/config/citrus-http-config.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd">
   (...)
   <citrus:channel-endpoint id="fileEndpoint" channel="fileChannel"/>
   <file:outbound-channel-adapter id="fileOutboundAdapter" 
                            channel="fileChannel" 
                            directory="file:/"/>
   <si:channel id="fileChannel"/>
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Thanks from advance.

@Edit:
I have added spring-integration-file.jar to project classpath but error is still the same.

@Edit2:
Well it looks like I messed up while I was adding jar to classpath. Now I have diffrent error:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd; lineNumber: 479; columnNumber: 71; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'integration:smartLifeCycleAttributeGroup' to a(n) 'attribute group' component.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. 
First of all, after properly added spring-integration-file.jar to classpath I had wrong version number in dependency in pom.xml 
So after added this jar: spring-integration-file-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar
I had to add this to pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-file</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```